# Dynamic subject in Mandrill e-mail using rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mandrill

I have passed dynamic content to the body of the email. But looking at the [API docs](https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.JSON.html) the subject params only accepts a string and not an array.

Is there a way to pass a dynamic subject? I would like to pass the name of the recipient in the subject

I have the following right now:

```
    m = Mandrill::API.new ENV['MANDRILL_APIKEY']
message = {
:subject=> template.subject,
:from_name=> template.name,
:from_email=> template.from + "@" + email_domain,
:to=>mails,
:global_merge_vars=> [
  { :name => 'IMAGE', :content => image_tag},
      ],
:html=>email_template,
:preserve_recipients => false,
:merge_vars => variables, 
}
```

Comment: Why can't you concatenate the desired string together, like you are doing with the "from" email address?

Comment: Because it has to be dynamic and different for every email I sent. Unlike the from email address which is the same for all.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Mandrill reads merge variables in the subject as well. So it is as simple as adding `*|SOME_VAR|*` in your subject text and then passing it as a parameter in the `merge_vars`.

More details [here](https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205582777-Can-I-use-merge-tags-in-my-subject-line-or-other-headers-).